# BIOS update not responding

Tags: thinkpad, bios

I'm using a Thinkpad T480, and there's a BIOS update, but when I click update below it closes, then in two seconds reappears with no changes.

What gives?

[image]

Comment: Probably it needs Windows.

Comment: Haa! Let's see. Something appears to have installed. It might just be the messaging that was off.

Comment: No, there's no UEFI update file published that can be used from Ubuntu/Linux. There is a "BIOS Update (Bootable CD) for Windows 10 (64-bit) - ThinkPad T480" that in spite of the Win10 reference is just an ISO file that can be burned to a CD and *maybe* USB.